# Vertica new-line CR LF replace

Tags: replace, newline, vertica

I have a column in vertica which I wish to export to .csv.
The problem is that this column has CRLF in the middle, meaning that the export reads each line as two lines. Example of input(the EOF delimiter was copy pasted from Vertica):

```
First part
Second part
```

I tried the REPLACE option but it does not replace the sequence.

```
select TABLE, REPLACE(column_name, '\r\n', 'FUFU') from DB;
```

The command does replace random letters.

Hence I start to question if there is a CRLF (Notepad++ found it) or if there is some other character hidden there which I fail to replace...

Any help on what are other possible causes for the new line (I tried \n, \c, \r and any possible combinations...) or how to see it other than in Notepad (directly in Vertica?) will be greatly appreciated...

Alternatively, I found no way to explicitly define in Vertica the EOF characters on export - does something like this exist?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check how to use **Extended String Literals** in the Vertica's SQL Reference Manual.

Example:

```
create table a ( id integer , txt varchar(20) ) ;
insert into a values ( 1 , 'abc' ) ;
insert into a values ( 2 , e'def\r\nrghi' ) ;
insert into a values ( 3 , e'ij\r\nklm' ) ;
insert into a values ( 4 , 'poq' ) ;
```

Then, to replace \r\n sequences - for example - with a space:

```
SQL=> select id, replace(txt, e'\r\n', ' ' ) from a order by id ;
 id | replace  
----+----------
  1 | abc
  2 | def rghi
  3 | ij klm
  4 | poq
(4 rows)
```

Comment: did you notice the difference? '\r\n' --> E'\r\n'

Answer (score 2):

```
 REGEXP_REPLACE(text, '(?>\r\n|\n|\r)', ' ')
```